# twig templates how do I extend or prepend sheets onto end of existing list

Tags: php, templates, symfony, twig, template-engine

I am looking to extend a stylesheet list in twig.  I have stripped down the code as much as possible to illustrate what im trying to achieve.

**base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Some title</title>

    {% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    {% endblock %}

  </head>

  <body>
    {% block content %}
        .. content for body goes here etc
    {% endblock content %}

  </body>

<!-- rest of template --!>
```

I then reuse the base template but I dont want to relist all of the style sheets I just want to add one on the end of the list?

**template that uses base**

```
{% extends 'sjQueryBundle::base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
<link href="css/sales-journal.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  some template stuff here
{% endblock content %}
```

The problem with the above is it replaces the style-sheet block entirely I'm just looking to add  sales-journal.css onto the end?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need is to call [`parent()`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/parent.html) method, which will render contents of the parent block

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link href="css/sales-journal.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Complementing @thecatontheflat, I recomend you to use Assetic for asset management. Take a look at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

Using Assetic you can use filters (for example for SASS or LESS), combine several files into one, minify your code... and much more!

For example, to use Assetic you only need to change your code in this way:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 'css/bootstrap.min.css' 'css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css' 
                   'css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css' 
                   output='css/styles.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset_url}}" />
{% endblock %}
```